# Tree data structure (Generics)

Tags: java, generics, tree

I'm implementing a simple Tree data structure.
My goal is to create an object of type Node inside the Tree class.
In this case I do not understand how to manage Generics.

This is my thin Tree structure:

```
public class RBT<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {

    Node<K,V> a = null;
    Node<Integer,String> b = null;

    public RBT() {
        this.a = new Node<K,V>(new Integer(1), new String("node1")); // ERROR
        this.b = new Node<Integer, String>(new Integer(1), new String("node1"));

        this.a = this.b; // ERROR!
    }

    public void newNode(K key, K value) {
        Node<K,V> test = new Node<K,V>(key, value); // ERROR
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RBT<Integer,String> rbt = new RBT<Integer,String>();
        rbt.newNode(new Integer(2), new String("node2")); // ERROR!
    }
}
```

And this is my Node representation:

```
public class Node<K,V> {
    private Node<K,V> father;
    private Node<K,V> left;
    private Node<K,V> right;

    private K key;
    private V value;

    Node(K key, V value) {
        this.father = this.left = this.right = null;

        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Finally I found another interesting solution. I've declared the Node class as private inside the RBT class `private class Node { }` (note I've omitted <K,V>). This could make easier the management of the Generics.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

```
this.a = new Node<K,V>(new Integer(1), new String("node1")); // ERROR
```

You can't add K,V as generics while you give it the exact types.
So remove it

```
 this.a = new Node(new Integer(1), new String("node1"));
```

Secondly,

```
this.a = this.b; // ERROR!
```

`this.a` has the generics `<K,V>` while `this.b` has `<Integer,String>`. So there is a mismatch which you can solve by casting it since you know exactly `K,V` is going to be `Integer,String`.

```
this.a = (Node<K, V>) this.b;
```

---

Also your method signature is wrong here

```
public void newNode(K key, K value) {
                           ^ should be V
        Node<K,V> test = new Node(key, value); // ERROR
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Murat, I replaced the code with your suggestions, but `this.a = (RBT<K, V>.Node<K, V>) this.b;` throws the follow error error: `cannot find symbol: this.a = (RBT<K, V>.Node<K, V>) this.b; symbol: class Node, location: class RBT<K,V>`

Comment: finally your solution is similar to @Yi Zhang's code. Add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` before the constructor signature, bypass  the problem, thanks a lot. But I'm still not convinced.

Comment: @JohnMòf This is not the problem of the compiler. The compiler tells you that you are doing a unchecked cast, because you know that `K,V` is going to be `String, Integer`, but the compiler doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob with Generic of Java.And you can do like this.

```
public class RBT<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {

    Node<K,V> a = null;
    Node<Integer,String> b = null;

    public RBT() {
        this.a = new Node(new Integer(1), new String("node1")); // ERROR
        this.b = new Node<Integer, String>(new Integer(1), new String("node1"));

        this.a = (Node<K, V>) this.b; // ERROR!
    }

    public void newNode(K key, V value) {
        Node<K,V> test = new Node(key, value); // ERROR
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RBT<Integer,String> rbt = new RBT<Integer,String>();
        rbt.newNode(new Integer(2), new String("node2")); // ERROR!
    }
}
```

and forgive my poor English.I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: This could be generate a `warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast`

Comment: @JohnMòf Yep,the compiler would generate a warning,but it doesn't affect the result.And I don't know how to fix the warning except add **SuppressWarning** above it.Sorry.

Comment: I investigated more, you are right. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

As you already discovered, you cannot write

```
new Node<K, V>
```

You have to specify the types.

```
Node<Integer, String> node = new Node<Integer, String>(new Integer(1), new String("anything"))
```

Comment: `K` and `V` are actually "types" in the place he has used them... The problem is that he is not passing objects of those types as parameters...